# Find continuous approximation of $f$.

Tags: analysis, approximation

$f(x)$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and $f(x) \in R[a,b]$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ find $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ which are continuous on $[a,b]$ such that:

(a) $g(x) \le f(x) \le h(x)$, $\forall x \in [a,b] $

(b) $\int_a^b [h(x) - g(x)] ds < \epsilon$.

I thought about looking for piecewise linear functions which are decided up to the superior and inferior of $g$ and $h$ on intervals of a certain partition of $[a,b]$ but since $f(x)$ is not necessary continuous I can hardly go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take the upper and lower Darboux sums and approximate those with piecewise linear functions.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed?

Comment: You can find piecewise constant functions $g'$ and $h'$ (the Darboux sums) that satisfy (a) and (b) since $f$ is Riemann integrable. Now approximate $g'$ and $h'$ by piecewise linear functions $g$ and $h$.

Comment: @X.TChen I think it's the method that you wanted to do; but you don't need continuous. Since you know $f$ is integrable, that means that there exists a partition $P$ with $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$. And $L(f, P) = \int_a^b g(x)dx$, and $U(f, P) = \int_a^b h(x) dx$

Comment: @Klaus How I think: Partition $\Delta$ : $a=x_0<\cdots <x_n = b$. For $x_i$ and $m_i = \min_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}\{f(x)\}$ let $g(x_i) = \min\{m_i,m_{i+1}\}$ and connect each point with straight line then get $g(x)$. For $h(x)$ do verbatim. But I am not sure this satisfies condition b.

Comment: @X.TChen No, draw a piecewise constant function. You can make it continuous by adding small triangles. By changing the slope you can make the additional area as small as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$1).\ $ Draw a picture of of what you want and use it to do the following:

$2).\ $ There is a partition $P=\{a,x_2,\cdots, x_{n-1},b\}$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon.$

$3).\ $ on each subinterval $[x_i,x_{i-1})$, define a piecewise continuous linear function $g$, by considering the linear segments from $(x_i,f(x_i))$ to $(x_{i-1},f(x_{i-1}))$ for $a=x_1\le x_i\le x_n=b$.

$4).\ $ Show that $L(f,P)\le \int^b_ag(x)dx\le U(P,f)$ so that  $\left |\int^b_ag(x)dx-\int^b_af(x)dx  \right |<\epsilon$.

Comment: Is $g$ less than $f$?

Comment: No, but the area under the graph of $g$ is less than $U$ and greater than $L$ and that is what you want. I suggest you draw a picture of an arbitrary subinterval $[x_i,x_{i-1}]$ to see what is going on.